# Error in starting project after webpack update to version 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, nodes, date-fns

I'm getting 23 errors of this kind when I'm trying to run my project:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@remotelock/react-week-scheduler/index.mjs
> 5:0-42 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'date-fns/add_hours' in
> 'C:\Users\platform2-frontend\node_modules@remotelock\react-week-scheduler'
> Did you mean 'index.js'? BREAKING CHANGE: The request
> 'date-fns/add_hours' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as
> fully specified (probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript
> Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a
> '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
> The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully
> specified. Add the extension to the request.

I tried updating the `date-fns` library to the latest version as well as the `react-week-scheduler` library, also I changed the way I'm importing date-fns function: instead of importing the whole library in my files I'm important like this:

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns'
```

I also updated react to the latest version 18 instead of version 16.14 which I used to have.

Comment: Can you add your package.json to the question?